# getting error after creating multiple store

Tags: multistore, configuration, magento-1

After done configuration as per the link http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html#gref

I am getting below error,

C:\wamp\www\magento\books../app/Mage.php was not found

Please help me in this

Code inside books folder index.php file below

```
<?php   

if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '<')===true) {
    echo  '<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
<div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
<h3 style="margin:0; font-size:1.7em; font-weight:normal; text-transform:none; text-align:left; color:#2f2f2f;">
Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version.</h3></div><p>Magento supports PHP 5.3.0 or newer.
<a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/install" target="">Find out</a> how to install</a>
 Magento using PHP-CGI as a work-around.</p></div>';
    exit;
}

/**
 * Compilation includes configuration file
 */
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '../app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}    
require MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/bootstrap.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

#Varien_Profiler::enable();

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);

/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Comment: What's your folder for website and also let me know exact path of folder and root folder path

Comment: I tested this in my local wamp server, path of the folder: C:\wamp\www\magento\books, root folder path: C:\wamp\www\magent

Comment: Please add your index.php code in question which is inside the `C:\wamp\www\magento\books` folder

Comment: below code i added in .htaccess file inside books folder                         SetEnvIf Host .*base.* MAGE_RUN_CODE="base";
SetEnvIf Host .*magento_site_2.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE="books";

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your index.php file

```
<?php   

if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '<')===true) {
    echo  '<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
<div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
<h3 style="margin:0; font-size:1.7em; font-weight:normal; text-transform:none; text-align:left; color:#2f2f2f;">
Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version.</h3></div><p>Magento supports PHP 5.3.0 or newer.
<a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/install" target="">Find out</a> how to install</a>
 Magento using PHP-CGI as a work-around.</p></div>';
    exit;
}

/**
 * Compilation includes configuration file
 */
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', 'C:/wamp/www/magento/');

$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . 'includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . 'app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}    
require MAGENTO_ROOT . 'app/bootstrap.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

#Varien_Profiler::enable();

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);

/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Comment: getting same error after used above code in index.php inside books folder,   can you provide your mail id, so that will send screen shots of my configurations for multiple store, so that it will easy to find my mistake if missed out any configuration settings

Comment: echo $mageFilename;exit; just after the `$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '../app/Mage.php';` let me know what is the result

Comment: No error, but with empty webpage.

Comment: Updated code check it and upload magento root .htaccess there without any change

Comment: Hi Prashant, Now my site is working fine, but am unable to make difference in your index.php, what changes u have done can u guide me. so that i dont want to do things without understand whats happening while errors fixed. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I have changed here `define('MAGENTO_ROOT', 'C:/wamp/www/magento/');` when you use getcwd() it will gives you current directory path so path like `C:/wamp/www/magento/books/../app/Mage.php` it won't work so i have changed `MAGENTO_ROOT`.

Comment: Nice, I also tested this but not checked in browser, i thought we should not change default MAGENTO_ROOT define variable value :)

Comment: If you don't want change it you can simply use `$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';`

Comment: If it helps you,mark as accepted.

Comment: Hi I found new issue, that Category set to Books store is not applied , instead default categories are applied for Books store setup. I think still Multiple Option not done proper.

Comment: Have you created root category?

Comment: Yes my root category is Books, and it was set to Books store

Comment: You need to create root category and assign it to new website

Comment: I rechecked settings are fine

Comment: Website - Books
(Code: firstbookstore),   Store- Books
(Root Category: Books) , Store-view Awesome Books
(Code: awesomebooks)